# Help with Calculus Optimization Problem!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, circles, area

We wish to construct a rectangular auditorium with a stage shaped as a semicircle of radius $r$, as shown in the diagram below (white is the stage and green is the seating area). For safety reasons, light strips must be placed on the perimeter of the seating area. If we have $45\pi + 60$ meters of light strips, what should $r$ be so that the seating area is maximized?

[image]

So I first set the width of the seating area to 2r, and the depth to be x. The perimeter would then be  $2x + 2r + \pi r$ = $45\pi + 60$. The problem asks us to maximize the area, though, so it's $2rx - (\pi r^2)/2$. I can solve the equation in terms of x so that it becomes $x = (45\pi + 60 - r(\pi + 2))/2$. Unfortunately, I'm stuck from this point on, so any hint that you could give me would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You have area expressed in terms of $r$ and $x$, and you've used the fixed perimeter to express $x$ in terms of $r$.  Can you use these two to express $A$ as a function of $r$ alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximization problem you want to solve is 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\max_{2x+(2+\pi)r=45\pi+60} r(4x-\pi r) $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{8+6\pi}\max_{4x+(4+2\pi)r=90\pi+120} (4+3\pi)r(4x-\pi r). $$
By letting $A=(4+3\pi)r$ and $B=4x-\pi r$ this can be written as
$$ \frac{1}{8+6\pi}\max_{A+B=90\pi+120} AB $$
and by the AM-GM inequality it equals
$$ \frac{1}{8+6\pi}\left(60+45\pi\right)^2 = \frac{225}{2}(4+3\pi),$$
achieved by $r=15$.

Answer (score 1):

so you are going correctly

you have $$2x+2r+\pi r=45\pi+60$$

so $$2x=45\pi+60-2r-\pi r$$

now you have $$area=2x*r-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$$

now replace the value of 2x in the area equation from the 1st equation
to obtain the area in a single variable so that you can calculate the derivative w.r.t.  r.
$$A=(45\pi+60-2r-\pi r)*r-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$$

the area becomes 
$$A=45\pi r+60r-2r^2-\pi r^2-\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$$

differentiate it w.r.t. r

$$\frac{dA}{dr}=45\pi+60-2\pi r-4r-\pi r=0$$

thus $$r=\frac{45\pi+60}{3\pi+4}=15$$
thus $$r=15$$
thus $$2x=45\pi + 60- 2*15-\pi *15=30+ 30* \pi $$

maximum area is $$A=45*pi*15+60*15-2*15^2-\pi *15^2- \pi * \frac{15^2}{2}$$

also, check the second derivative to confirm that it is indeed maximum.

Comment: $\pi$ is written as \pi between dollar signs

Comment: @James thank you for your answer! Can you clarify your answer a little bit? For instance, what do you mean when you say 'w.r.t'? And can you clarify on what I should substitute for what? I substituted the second equation into the first and ultimately just got 45$\pi$ = 45$\pi$. Thanks again!

Comment: you want to obtain the area equation in either term of r of x so that you can differentiate the area w.r.t. either r or x to now the value for which the area is maximum it was easy to obtain the area equation in terms of r than x that's why I   replaced the value of x in area equation

Comment: read the answer again I edited it a little for your understanding!

Answer (score 1):

The back wall has measure $2r$
The side walls have measure $x$

The perimeter $P = \pi r + 2r + 2x = 60 + 45 \pi$

The seating area is $A = x(2r) - \frac 12 \pi r^2$

Objective:
Maximize $A = x(2r) - \frac 12 \pi r^2$

Constrained by: $\pi r + 2r + 2x = 60 + 45 \pi$

Usually, we use the constraint to find a way to represent one variable as a function of the other, and substitute into our objective.

Then we differentiate the objective and set it do $0$ to find the critical points.

$ 2x = 60 + 45 \pi-\pi r - 2r\\
A = (60 + 45 \pi-\pi r - 2r)r - \frac {\pi}{2} r^2 = (60 + 45 \pi) r +(-\frac {3\pi}{2}  - 2)r^2 \\
A' = 60 + 45\pi -(3\pi +4)r = 0\\
r = \frac {60 + 45\pi}{(3\pi +4)}$